# Issue Calling AJAX script from a subdomain (ExpressionEngine)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a site with a main domain with several subdomains.  I use an AJAX call to send out emails.  It works fine from the main site (www), but not the microsites.  My file structure is:

```
/www
   emailsend.php

   /sub1
       emailsend.php
   /sub2
       emailsend.php
   /sub3 
       emailsend.php
```

And the domains are www.hawksite.com, sub1.hawksite.com, sub2.hawksite.com, sub3.hawksite.com. Here is the call:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "/emailsend.php",
      data: { loc: locString, mes: message}
    });
```

When I check the inspector, the xhr request is to

http://sub1.hawksite.com/emainsend.php

but I get a 404 not found error.  The site is built in Expression Engine if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does /emailsend.php exists in all subdomains? If not you have to use the full url on your AJAX request, you also have to consider [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) otherwise you'll get an invalid response

Comment: I was trying to put it on all subdomains because of CORS.  It didn't work going above the subdomain document root.  So I'm trying putting it in each subdomain directory to avoid cross scripting.  I don't want to mess with the header because it's in Expression Engine and it might affect something else.

Comment: You then need to make sure that emailsend.php is in the root folder of every subdomain. By the way, make sure that you use some kind of [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) validation otherwise you'll end up with a free email relay for spamers

Comment: It is in the root folder of the subdomains, but I still get a 404:

http://sub1.hawksite.com/emailsend.php is not found...

There htaccess rules that might be it not sure

Comment: that is simple enough to test, rename .htaccess to something else

Comment: That might mess up Expression Engine Claudio

Comment: Yes, but for the purpose of testing the url will be suficiente, you can work on the rewrite exception after. Although I think expression engine is CodeIgniter therefore the rewrite rules actually test for the file first and then rewrite